# Angular2, links not working with lazy loaded modules, but worked on page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have `Angular2` project built with `Angular-CLI`. I'm using lazy loading for modules which I guess causing my problem.

After I load project with `Module A` on browser, and I click navigation link which load `Module B` (with lazy loading) then clicking on simple link, ie.

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Click me</a>
```

it doesn't work, nothing happened, but when I refresh page on `Module B`, same links start working.

Does anyone have a clue why this is happening?

I checked on network tab and in both cases, all requests look the same, only difference that when **switching** between modules page is loading whole application with `Module A`, and then just loads required files for `Module B`.

I know this is not a very detailed description but for now I don't know what to say more.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. The problem was about how I've inserted HTML chunk in angular template. 
Before I was using `[innerHTML]="fullDescription"` property which prevents from clicking in links.

Solution
`<div innerHTML="{{fullDescription}}"></div>`

Also I had to omit `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` from `DomSanitizer`.

Hope this will help someone.